# Passing variables as parameters to @Url.Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How to pass variables as parameters to @Url.Action ?

I populate a Menu control using @Url.Action.

**List:** 
- childitem (it's populated from stored procedure) 
**Fields:** 
- TX_MENU: "My menu item" 
- TX_ACTION: "Index" 
- TX_CONTROLLER: "Buzon"

I'd like to populate my Menu control assigning

`href=@Url.Action("SomeAction", "SomeController")`

How could I pass variables as parameters with @.

I tried this code, but failed:

```
<ul>
      @foreach (var itemchild in childitem)
      {
          <li class='last'><a href='@Url.Action(@itemchild.TX_ACTION, @itemchild.TX_CONTROLLER)'>@itemchild.TX_MENU</a>
          </li>
      }
</ul>
```

`@itemchild.TX_ACTION` and `@itemchild.TX_CONTROLLER` are not recognized as variables inside `@Url.Action`.

Comment: What is the exact error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should white it like this:

```
<ul>
      @foreach (var itemchild in childitem)
      {
          <li class='last'><a href='@Url.Action(itemchild.TX_ACTION, itemchild.TX_CONTROLLER)'>@itemchild.TX_MENU</a>
          </li>
      }
</ul>
```

Don't escape your variables with `@` symbol when you in `Url.Action()` helper